# Java : Read text file. Filter selected words. Input into an ArrayList

Tags: java, io

> *Even if anyone can point me to similar question would be appreciated.*

So i have this text file which has nodes and connections(basically graph) written in form of

> nodes[ id]

and

> edge[source destination]

There is a certain pattern to  input data in text file.
Text file with everything inside [square brackets]. '

> So the heirarhcy goes entire_text_inside_a[
>       node[   id 1]    node[   id 2]    edge[    source 1    destination 2]   ]

Now i want to get values of id and store in a list seperately and edge in a seperate.
ME being new to java I/O have a general idea of input output a text file but what about the FILTER part.

Thank You in Advance.

A small piece of text file

```
 node [
    id 152
    label "Milan"
    Country "Italy"
    Longitude 9.18951
    Internal 1
    Latitude 45.46427
    type "Data Centre and MAN"
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 1
    LinkLabel "Operational network managed end-to-end"
  ]
```

If i get the answer i will post it.

Comment: To filter a text file you have to read it and save it into a string and then parse the string to get the data you want.

Comment: To parse the string you could use regular expressions (regex), [Here is the Oracle lessons about regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: @Abhinav From node you want "id" and from edge you want which part?? (source, target, LinkLabel). Also will there be multiple nodes and edges like you defined??

Comment: @SachinSarawgi yes i am making a graph using maps/hash and there are hundreds of them in a text file.Plus its my first time in java doing any of it.

Comment: thank you for link @aleb2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a BufferReader to check each a line for "[" character.  After finding the "[" character check whether the leading text contains "node" or "edge".  Pass the corresponding ArrayList into a method that keeps going down the lines of the text file to find either "id" or "source" on a line.  When it finds a line with "id" or "source" parse that line to extract the information you want and add it to your ArrayList.  If the line contains a "]" break out of the method and return to your original code.  Keep looping through the lines of the file until you receive a null line.

Comment: I can use BufferReader to check each line. Awesome!

I don't know how to get the value in between "[" and "]".

Comment: Yes, you can use BufferReader's readLine() method, which returns a String with all of the text on a single line.  Each time you use readLine() it'll move down to the next line in the file.  Strings have a method called contains() where you can search the String for a character sequence.  In this case we could look for only the "[" or "]" characters.